# How can I create an instance which is defined in \App_Code in Vs 2019?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I use Vs 2019 to create a project, you can see Image for the project structure.

I define a class named `HandelRecord` in HandelRecor.cs file located in `\App_Code` folder, and I hope to use it in Default.aspx.cs.

But `HandelRecord aHandelRecord = new HandelRecord()` can't be compiled , how can I fix it?

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
using System;

namespace TempDB
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                setLabel();
            }
        }

        private void setLabel()
        {          
            HandelRecord aHandelRecord = new HandelRecord();    //Can't be compiled
        }
    }
}
```

**HandleRecord.cs**

```
using System;
...

namespace TempDB.App_Code
{
    public class HandelRecord
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Image 1**
[image]

**Added Content:**

To: Albert D. Kallal,  Thanks!

Is it a bad way to place .cs file to `\App_Code`?  You can see Image A, I have to set *Compile* option for the .cs file by myself.

If I place .cs file to root folder of the project, the Vs 2019 set the *Compile* option for the .cs file automatically, you can see Image B.

**Image A**
[image]

**Image B**
[image]

Comment: Do you have an update on this question? Albert submitted the latest update.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I place class file \*.cs in root folder of a project when I use Vs 2019 (Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75334818/should-i-place-class-file-cs-in-root-folder-of-a-project-when-i-use-vs-2019-m)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on that .cs file in app_code. Check the build opiton and change it to "compile"

eg this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But I get the same error after I try your way.

Comment: `E:\ASP.NET_TempDB\TempDB\Default.aspx.cs(23,13,23,25): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HandelRecord' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: It works for me. However this might be a web site and not a web application in your case. Do a rebuild all just to be sure

Comment: Standard fair to drop in (add) a new class to app_code. I'm not 100% sure, but I did think (at one time), right click on app_folder->add new item->class. I seem to recall that this would set the properties as "compile". However, it seems not. So, just remember that extra step. Note that the "do not copy" is fine if this is a web site "application". However, if this is a web site, then quite sure copy to output is required.