# Should I place class file *.cs in root folder of a project when I use Vs 2019 (Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019)?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

When I use Vs 2012 Express edition to create a website , I remember I should place the class file *.cs  in the system folder `\App_Code`, and Vs 2012 can compile these files automatically. It's OK.

When I use Vs 2019 (Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019), I find the  the class file *.cs  in the system folder `\App_Code` can't be compiled automatically, I have to set it by myself, you can see Image A.

But if I place  the class file *.cs in  in root folder of a project , they can be compiled automatically, it seems that Vs 2019 set *Compile* option as default,  you can see Image B.

Is is a bad way to place the class file *.cs  in the system folder `\App_Code` when I use Vs 2019 ?

**Image A**
[image]

**Image B**
[image]

Comment: _App_Code_ is a special folder where you put _source_ files that are compiled by the IIS process workflow the first time your app receive a request and, if you update them, they are recompiled on the fly.

Comment: As a general rule, yes, you do have to tag the class as "compile". I did think that adding a class "used" to tag the code as such. I just can't remember. However, one is not "very" often adding a class to app_code and thus not a huge deal. However, I dumped using app_code, and create a folder called MyCode. The BIG reason for this was Roslyn compiler. For a web "application", then build compiles all code. However, noteworthy exception is that IIS will try to compile code in app_code, and thus I don't use it anymore. Not a huge deal, but I prefer to force the issue what gets compiled at build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not good or bad to place a class file *.cs in the system folder `App_Code` when you use VS2019 or some other VS, it depends on your goal for those files.

**TLDR**: put non user control sources in `App_Code` if you need server-side behavior (on the fly updates), but don't mark its build action as `compile` but rather `content`, and therefore forget about benefiting from IntelliSense.

For a website project, you have the special folders `Bin` and `App_Code`, for code shared between pages. Files inside App_Code do not have to be source code, it can be a content file. Files inside are handled by asp.net in special ways ([1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/t990ks23(v=vs.100))).

Source code inside `App_code` and subfolders are automatically compiled at runtime. When the website is running, you can update those source code, and they will be recompiled on the fly, just like *Live unit testing* in VS ([1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/t990ks23(v=vs.100))). This will happen when the website is running on the server too ([2](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/07/appcode-folder-doesnt-work-with-web.html)).

> The App_Code folder and its special status in an ASP.NET Web
> application makes it possible to create custom classes and other
> source-code-only files and use them in your Web application without
> having to compile them independently. ([1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/t990ks23(v=vs.100)))

But

> User controls are not allowed in the App_Code folder. This includes
> both single-file user controls and user controls that use the
> code-behind model. Putting a user control .in the App_Code directory
> causes the user control's code to be compiled out of its required
> sequence and therefore is not allowed. Note that user controls do not
> need to be in the App_Code folder; they are already available to pages
> anywhere in the application. ([1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/t990ks23(v=vs.100)))

I add that you should not add source code in `App_Code` and leave it marked `compile` as `build action`, because then it will be both compiled by VS and asp.net, leading to duplicate references. Instead, leave it as `content`, but then IntelliSense won't see them as source code. ([2](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/07/appcode-folder-doesnt-work-with-web.html))

Vishal R Joshi ([2](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/07/appcode-folder-doesnt-work-with-web.html)) gives the piece of advice:

> You can add code files under any folder call it “CodeFolder”,
> “Controllers” or anything that makes sense in your project… Just avoid
> putting them under “App_Code” unless you specifically want the server
> side compilation behavior… ([2](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/07/appcode-folder-doesnt-work-with-web.html))

References:

1. [Shared Code Folders in ASP.NET Web Sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/t990ks23(v=vs.100))
2. [App_Code folder doesn’t work with Web Application Projects (WAPs)](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/07/appcode-folder-doesnt-work-with-web.html)